# Get an Array value from mysql result JSON on Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I have a mysql column contain Array in it. And when printing this row that contain column in `console.log(collection[0])` The result is:

```
    RowDataPacket {
  id: 6,
  title: 'fsd',
  createddate: '2016-04-14 00:16:29',
  tag: 'fsdsd',
  img1: '[\'12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg\', \'12071715_826061364175214_103377995_n.jpg\', \'12076929_10207206326744146_1386812779_n.jpg\']',
  img1big: '[\'small_12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg\', \'small_12071715_826061364175214_103377995_n.jpg\', \'small_12076929_10207206326744146_1386812779_n.jpg\']' }
```

and i want to print the value `12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg` to view. I used a method like this:

```
{% for i in collection %}     
 {{i.img1[0]}}
{% endfor %}
```

But the view showed only first character of a string:

```
[
```

The result of `{{i.img1}}` is :

```
['12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg', '12071715_826061364175214_103377995_n.jpg', '12076929_10207206326744146_1386812779_n.jpg']
```

The question is, how can i print `12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg` on the view?
P/s: I tried to use both **JSON.parse()** and **JSON.stringify()** for some cases in both controller and view, but no uses.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The value for collection[0] seems to be a string. Somewhere in your code you'll need to parse the string into an object ([JSON.parse(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

Comment: used both JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify for some tries, but no luck :(
And i tried both on controller and view too.

Comment: i could be wrong, but it seems that when that that object is put in (or when taken out) of the db, something is invalidating the structure.  you might need to store different.  I got it to work in a kinda hacked up way...see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvdLb07/)

Comment: though about **enctype="multipart/form-data"** when input data. But i tried to input data manually and still not work. The data on img1 column is exactly like that : **['12071331_184535658548108_1612982316_n.jpg', '12071715_826061364175214_103377995_n.jpg', '12076929_10207206326744146_1386812779_n.jpg']**

Answer (score 0):

If you want display your image on a view, what you need is not the image name but the image path.

For example, if you store all images under public/images folder. You can use `<img src="/images/{{i.img1}}"/>` to display your photos.

Comment: yeah i know, but the point is {{i.img1}} only display the first string of the main string.